# How to use MotionLayout, MotionScene, ConstraintSet in jetpack compose?

Tags: android, android-animation, android-jetpack-compose, android-motionlayout, constraintset

I'm trying to implement something like this animation in jetpack compose and from what I've laid my eyes up until this point makes me think I should use `MotionLayout`, `ConstraintSet`, `MotionScene` but the [documentation](https://github.com/androidx/constraintlayout/wiki/Introduction-to-MotionLayout-in-Compose) is poor and I don't get much of it.

[image]

Can anyone point me to some examples or to a better documentation?

Answer (score 3):

We have not had a documentation push on ConstraintLayoutCompose (the library that contains MotionLayout) because 1.0 of ConstrainLayoutCompose has not been released.

ConstrainLayoutCompose will contain a limited subset of MotionLayouts features for Compose.

- The syntax can be found [here](https://github.com/androidx/constraintlayout/wiki/Compose-MotionLayout-JSON-Syntax).
- Some working examples can be found
  [here](https://github.com/androidx/constraintlayout/tree/main/projects/ComposeConstraintLayout)

If your animation needs are simple you might consider the Compose "native" Animations as well. (Google "Compose Animation")

We will continue to fill out all of the MotionLayout features next year.

MotionLayout is based on ConstraintLayout and as such you should also be familiar
with ConstraintLayout.

The general principals of MotionLayout work the same so all the Overview information from classic views applies.
Concepts such as:

[ConstraintSet](https://youtu.be/MiD5sILCDBI)
[Transitions](https://youtu.be/m7VpGPdlDvQ) 
[keyPosition](https://youtu.be/3HQMCyAkWTE)
[KeyCycle](https://youtu.be/jUm_AkH_mAQ)

It is using a new [json5 syntax](https://github.com/androidx/constraintlayout/wiki/Compose-MotionLayout-JSON-Syntax)

Comment: When will you publish MotionLayout for Compose on official documentation?

Comment: We set MotionLayout as Experimental as we continue to fill out the API and Implementation. After we stabilize the API we will ramp up and effort to document the it. 
We have no official timeline.